# QuickSorting Linked Lists in C

Tags: c, linked-list, quicksort

I am trying to become more familiar with recursion and I am trying to write a function recursively rather than iteratively... I am trying to create a quick-sort function for linked list, I keep reevaluating the code, but I don't know what I am missing, the code always leaves the last node on the list, for example...

```
input list ... 1->2->3->4->NULL
output list .. 4->NULL
```

here is my code ...

```
void lst_qsort(LIST *l){
    if(l==NULL || l->front==NULL || l->front->next==NULL)
        return;
    if(lst_length(l)<=1)
        return;

    LIST *lt = lst_create();
    LIST *pivot = lst_create();

    pivot->front = l->front;
    pivot->back = l->front;

    l->front = l->front->next;
    pivot->front->next = NULL;
    lt = lst_filter_leq(l, pivot->front->val);


    lst_qsort(lt);
    lst_qsort(l);
    lst_concat(l, lt);

}
```

NOTES `lst_filter_leq()` is a function that pulls out all occurrences of x<=cutoff point and returns a list of all the nodes pulled.

```
LIST * lst_filter_leq(LIST *lst, ElemType cutoff) {
    LIST *lst2 = lst_create();
    NODE *tmp = lst->front;
    int i = 0, n=1;

    while(lst->front != NULL){
        if(lst->front->val <= cutoff){
            lst_push_back(lst2, lst->front->val);
        }
        lst->front = lst->front->next;
    }
    lst->front = tmp;
    for(i=cutoff; i>=0; i--){
        n = lst_remove_all_slow(lst, i);
    }

    return lst2;
}
```

`lst_concat()` merges two list together

Comment: Do you really need `if(lst_length(l)<=1)` since you've already checked `l->front->next==NULL`, etc., above?

Comment: I think its this OR `|| l->front->next==NULL` as surely this means return when the next value after the front of the queue is NULL.. and I assume in a list the last value i.e. null is not considered an element

Comment: @PaulSullivan sadly, this is not the issue, however, the list is now empty

Comment: @e0k yes you are correct, I guess I don't need it, thanks

Comment: @e0k `lst_concat(l,lt)` causes `l` = `l`+`lt`...

Comment: NOTE: `lst_filter_leq()` is a function that may or may not be working correctly. Please post a [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `lst->front = lst->front->next` would seem to remove all items from the input list, even though only some items are added to `lst2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your code and your example. First, looks like creating `pivot` list is seemingly not necessary, as you use only `pivot->front->val`, which I assume is the first value on your list (because you earlier did `pivot->front = l->front`).

So for values [1, 2, 3, 4] you do the following in the first step (I use pseudo-code to show list members):

```
// you extracted '1' from your list, because you did l->front = l->front->next;
lt = lst_filter_leq([2, 3, 4], 1);
```

which means you end with nothing (none of the values on the list are less or equal than 1). Next you do quicksort of `l` (which is [2, 3, 4]) and then concatenate results of `l` and `lt`.

But when quicksorting [2, 3, 4] you receive nothing and quicksort [3, 4],
 which is nothing and [4].
And quicksorting of [4] returns [4]. Hence your result.

So looks what you forgot was inserting `pivot` between `l` and `lt` lists.

Working implementation using `glib` library for double-ended queues:

```
#include <glib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// defines to maintain compatibility with OP code
#define LIST GQueue
#define lst_create g_queue_new
#define lst_length g_queue_get_length

// lst_push_back implementation using GQueue
void lst_push_back(LIST *list, int val) {
    g_queue_push_tail(list, GINT_TO_POINTER(val));
}

// lst_pop_front implementation using GQueue
int lst_pop_front(LIST *list) {
    return GPOINTER_TO_INT(g_queue_pop_head(list));
}

// adds elements from list2 to list1
// list2 is destroyed afterwards
void lst_concat(LIST *list1, LIST *list2) {
    int length = lst_length(list2);
    int i, v;
    for (i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        v = lst_pop_front(list2);
        lst_push_back(list1, v);
    }
    g_queue_free(list2);
}

// filters 'list' elements
// elements less or equal 'value' are returned in newly created list
// elements greater than 'value' are left in 'list'
LIST *lst_filter_leq(LIST *list, int value) {
    LIST *lte = lst_create();
    LIST *gt  = lst_create();
    int length = lst_length(list);
    int i, v;
    for (i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        v = lst_pop_front(list);
        if (v <= value) {
            lst_push_back(lte, v);
        } else {
            lst_push_back(gt, v);
        }
    }
    lst_concat(list, gt);
    return lte;
}

void lst_qsort(LIST *l) {
    if (l == NULL) {
        return;
    }
    if (lst_length(l) <= 1) {
        return;
    }

    LIST *lt = lst_create();
    LIST *pivot = lst_create();

    int val = lst_pop_front(l);
    lst_push_back(pivot, val);

    // this function divides the list int two parts
    // elements less or equal 'val' are returned in lt list ("right" list)
    // elements greater than 'val 'are left in l list ("left" list)
    lt = lst_filter_leq(l, val);

    lst_qsort(lt); // sort "right" part of list

    lst_qsort(l);  // sort "left" part of list

    lst_concat(l, pivot); // add the pivot element
    lst_concat(l, lt);    // add right part of list
}

void printList(LIST *list) {
    GList *vList = g_queue_peek_head_link(list);
    while (vList != NULL) {
        printf("%d", GPOINTER_TO_INT(vList->data));
        vList = g_list_next(vList);
        if (vList != NULL) {
            printf("->");
        } else {
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
}

int main(void) {
    LIST *l = lst_create();
    lst_push_back(l, 4);
    lst_push_back(l, 3);
    lst_push_back(l, 2);
    lst_push_back(l, 1);

    printf("unsorted: ");
    printList(l);
    lst_qsort(l);
    printf("sorted: ");
    printList(l);

    g_queue_clear(l);

    lst_push_back(l, 1);
    lst_push_back(l, 2);
    lst_push_back(l, 3);
    lst_push_back(l, 4);

    printf("unsorted: ");
    printList(l);
    lst_qsort(l);
    printf("sorted: ");
    printList(l);

    g_queue_clear(l);

    srand(time(NULL));
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 16; ++i) {
        lst_push_back(l, rand() % 32);
    }
    printf("unsorted: ");
    printList(l);
    lst_qsort(l);
    printf("sorted: ");
    printList(l);

    g_queue_free(l);

    return 0;
}
```

Example output:

```
unsorted: 4->3->2->1
sorted: 4->3->2->1
unsorted: 1->2->3->4
sorted: 4->3->2->1
unsorted: 27->16->20->4->14->30->26->28->10->13->19->1->30->8->3->14
sorted: 30->30->28->27->26->20->19->16->14->14->13->10->8->4->3->1
```

Comment: If you never add the pivot back in, the list gets shorter by one each time.  It stops trying when there is only one node left, which is your sample result.

Comment: So are you suggesting i `concat(lt,pivot)` I'm sorry having trouble understanding your answer.

Comment: @MComp: You should concat (lt, pivot) and then (lt, l). Then `lt` is your sorted list.

Comment: @MComp Typically, a list gets separated into three parts: left, pivot, right. Then you recursively sort left and right, and finally reassemble the list from the three pieces. If you only divide the input into two lists, you run the risk that an input list with 2 items will result in a left list with 2 items, and a right list with 0 items, resulting in infinite recursion.

Comment: @MComp: If you did what I wrote you should then make your `l` point at the values returned in `lt`. Do the reverse: concat (l, pivot), then concat (l, lt), but you'll end with opposite-sorted list.

Comment: @nsilent22 actually, when I enter the example 4 3 2 1... the output is just 4... and when I have a long list it just shows one number

Comment: @MComp: Maybe you have some other bugs in your code, I don't know. I've updated my answer with an example code of `lst_sort` implementation that works. Made some defines to match namespace of your code. Of course this code isn't optimal (for example concatenating function just moves elements from one list to another), but that's just proof of concept. Hope this helps.

Comment: @nsilent22 sorry to waste your time, this whole time, my concat() function was the culprit! Thanks a lot! :D